Wifi disconnecting
Frequent Wi-Fi disconnections in Ubuntu 22.04 and 24.04, especially on specific laptop models like the HP Laptop 15s-fy5006TU, can be caused by several factors including driver issues, power management settings, or kernel compatibility. Here’s how you can troubleshoot and potentially fix the issue
Note: We have reinstalled the Ubuntu OS also we have reinstall Network also still issue is same

What is the question? As written this makes little sense.

While installing Ubuntu OS on the HP Laptop 15s-fy5006TU, the internet was not working properly. However, after switching to Windows OS, it worked fine. Please provide a solution to fix the issue.

Please be specific; installing Ubuntu OS is vague; as Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is available in 6 ISOs for Desktop (22.04, 22.04.1, 22.04.2 etc) & 6 ISOs for Server (again 22.04, 22.04.1 etc) with different kernels used on many of them (22.04 & 22.04.1 are the same kernel, but .2 & later differ) & Desktop & Server using different installers...   You've not been specific with what Ubuntu OS you're asking about (Ubuntu Server? Ubuntu Desktop? etc) and release/ISO can make a difference
